# MVC4 - Stuck at "The arguments for method cannot be inferred from usage"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on MVC4 project and after computer and Visual Studio (2013) reinstallation, I'm getting error

```
The type arguments for method 'EditRowTextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>
(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, 
 System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>,
 object, bool, bool, bool, bool, string, object)'
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

when I'm editing view with helpes with lamda expressions.

Moreover, VS gives me another error -

```
One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found.
Are you missing a reference?
```

I've never seen any of these errors in this project until now.

I tried almost everything - I set corect versions of .NET (4.5.1) and MVC in config, I set System.Web.Mvc to not copy local, I have added RazorViewEngine in ApplicationStart, none of that worked. I've also reinstalled MVC4.

Until reinstallation everything was just fine. Although I can build project and run it in IIS7 and everything is working perfectly,  it's really annoying, because I can't use expressions and Intellisence doesn't show anything from model Propperties.

Any help welcome!

Comment: Are you missing a reference? Are you using any nuget packages> If so check they are all correctly installed.

Comment: No, no references are missing. I have NuGet set to restore missing packages. I tried delete all packages and restore them, but without success.

Comment: Do you have access to VS 2012? I've had a lot of problems with 2013 complaining about errors that aren't really errors. If you do have access to 2012, try opening your solution in that, and see if you still have the same issue

Comment: I'm not really sure, if I have spare licence. Anyway, before reinstallation, I used same version of VS 2013 (school licence) and as I mentioned before, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heureka!

Problem was with references, as VS tried to use some binaries from GAC. I deleted all references to non-project binaries and created them again and problem was solved. It seems to be result of computer reinstall, where VS could load and see defined binaries from GAC, but it can't compile the project. After new referencing, VS managed to link correct versions and build project.